# ios advertisement sdk?

Tags: ios, ads

I swear I once read about an sdk that wraps both iAds, mobclix and admob but I cannot for the life of me find it. Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [adwhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

The practice you are looking for is called "ad mediation"

Answer (score 2):

Instead of AdWhirl check out the newer AdMob Mediation: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ios/mediation/

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Mopub](http://www.mopub.com/) for ad mediation.  I kinda like it.  Also check out [AppSDKs.com](http://www.appsdks.com/) for third party services and sdks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find a way to *make* iAds then you can use Apple's [iAd Producer](http://developer.apple.com/iad/iadproducer/) - http://developer.apple.com/iad/iadproducer/